# simple nav left and right alignment

Tags: css, html, html-lists, nav

So I've done this correctly before and found examples that work but I'm really trying to figure out **WHY** this is happening. Basically I want a navbar with a left and a right side, and the way I'm trying now has the right side being pushed down.

Do not hesitate to tell me to do this a completely different way! My main concern at this point is understanding what is happening as well as developing good industry best practices.

Heres my code

```
<header class="header">
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
nav {
    background: green;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;

}

.nav-left li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-right li {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your markup organization is very good. The reason why your links are being pushed down is because your `nav-left` is occupying the entire width of the navigation. Here is a **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/fejut75a/2/.

Note that you can adjust the padding to what you want.

CSS:

```
nav {
    background: green;
    padding: 15px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
}

.nav-left {
    float: left;
}

.nav-left ul li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-right ul li {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! Is there any particular reason why you included the "ul" tag before "li" in nav-left and nav-right but didn't and the prepending tags before a?

Comment: @user3085077 I think it is a better practice to be more specific in your CSS selectors so your code can be more well-maintained and organized. I would have put prepending tags before a, I just forgot to this time.

Comment: also any thoughts on the other solutions that worked? Does it matter which one you use or is it really just preference?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the *.nav-left* and *.nav-right* to float and clear the floating at the end of the *.nav* element. Modify the CSS as following:

```
nav {
  background: green;
}
nav:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '.';
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
}

.nav-left {
  float: left;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right;
}
```

In your original CSS file, the <nav> will allocate a <li> element height for rendering *.nav-left*, it results in why *.nav-right* be pushed down. Make both *.nav-left* and *.nav-right* floating, there's no pre-allocation spaces for these elements so they can stands the same y position.

After you making all elements under <nav> element floating, there's no element in it logically. So we have to add a pseudo content in the **nav:after** to make it render correct height.

Comment: thanks! any thoughts on the other solutions and why they may be better or worse?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cmbc6jw7/)

**Used display:inline-block;**

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    background: green;
    display:inline-block;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
}

li
{
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav-left {
    float: left;
}

.nav-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution as well.

Comment: thanks! Any thoughts on henrys solution? Is there any reason to go with one over the other?

Comment: See .nav-left and .nav-right are div's so they need floats(i mean float:left/right). Giving float to 'li' is like forcefully pushing them left/right, After that you just need to take care is making them on single line, so display:inline-block; are meant for that. I would never give floats to 'li' instead after making div float:left/right if i want text to right/left would use text-align:left/right. After all both @Henry and me have different answers but correct too.

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bloh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<!--css-->
nav {
    background: #ccc;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;

}
.nav-left{
   float:left;  
}
.nav-right{
   float:right;  
}
.nav-left li {
    float: left;

}

.nav-right li {
    float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2xsL8gow/